# Should HTTP Header Status match Body Status for RESTful calls

Tags: rest, web-services, http

Building a RESTful web service endpoint and wondering what the best practice is for HTTP header status versus the status found in the body of the response. Should they always match, or can they be different? For example, in the event of a bad request, it's really our application layer that does the parsing and processing of the payload. So in the event the request made it to the application layer, should the HTTP header show a 200 (indicating no problems with the transport) while the response body contains a 400 (indicating a bad request)? Or should they always match? Both 400 at the header and in the body?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is a good practice to be consistent. Thus, if you intend to return the HTTP status code in your JSON body, it should be the same as the HTTP status code.

If you want to add more details regarding your application errors. The [JSON-API standard](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors) defines some fields for JSON error bodies, such as:

- **code**: an application-specific error code, expressed as a string value. For example, you could have different codes for HTTP 400 status code.
- **title**: a short, human-readable summary of the problem that SHOULD NOT change from occurrence to occurrence of the problem, except for purposes of localization.
- **detail**: a human-readable explanation specific to this occurrence of the problem. Like title, this field’s value can be localized.

Imagine that your application has the following route to get the details of a song (identified by :id parameter) that belongs to an artist (identified by :artist_id parameter):

```
GET /artists/:artist_id/songs/:id
```

This request may produce two different Not Found errors:

1. when the artist is not found
2. when the song is not found

For both situations you will return a HTTP 404 status code. However, in your json body you can add more details:

1. when the artist is not found

   - code: 10
   - title: Artist Not Found
   - detail: The artist with id #{artist_id} does not exist
2. when the song is not found

   - code: 12
   - title: Song Not Found
   - detail: The song with id #{id} does not exist for #{artist.name}

I also recommend you take a look on how [JSON-API standard](http://jsonapi.org/format/) defines HTTP error code

Comment: A standard response body is the `application/problem+json` response. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807